# Add language files in civibuild

Tags: developer, civicrm-buildkit, civibuild

Checking the civibuild create parameters I do not see an option to include the translation/language files? That would be really helpfull, I now add them manually after a civibuild.

Answer (score 1):

What build type are you using, Erik?

The translation files are included in [drupal-demo](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/app/config/drupal-demo/download.sh#L33) but are commented out in [drupal-clean](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/app/config/drupal-clean/download.sh#L23).

Uncommenting the line:

```
 # extract-url --cache-ttl 172800 civicrm=http://download.civicrm.org/civicrm-l10n-core/archives/civicrm-l10n-daily.tar.gz
```

in `app/config/drupal-clean/download.sh` in your local buildkit will mean that localisation files are downloaded as part of the download.

You could go a step further and submit a PR that uncommented that line in buildkit, but that is probably for another day.

Comment: I am using drupal-clean Michael. Not sure if I will be able to do a PR on buildkit, that might be overreaching. And certainly not the best use of my talents :-)

Comment: OK - in case it wasn't clear, I have made the steps for fixing it for you locally a bit more obvious. Let me know if that solves it for you. The PR can be saved for another day :)